# How do I get a graph of CPU usage and Memory Usage from Azure Log Analytics filtered by namespace and grouped by service

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I was trying to get CPU usage and Memory usage for an application hosted on Azure. The application has multiple services and I wanted to get average CPU usage and Memory usage over time grouped by service for the application (namespace).

This is what I was thinking would work but does not seem to give me data over time.

```
KubePodInventory
| where Namespace contains 'namespace'
| extend InstanceName = strcat(ClusterId, '/', ContainerName)
| join Perf on InstanceName
| where ObjectName == 'K8SContainer' and CounterName == 'cpuUsageNanoCores'
| summarize CPU=avg(CounterValue)/1000000000 by LogTime=bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), ServiceName
```

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this working. Here is what I have gotten this to.

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == 'K8SContainer' and CounterName == 'cpuUsageNanoCores'
| summarize CPU=avg(CounterValue)/1000000000 by LogTime=bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), InstanceName
| lookup (KubePodInventory
| where Namespace=='namespace'
| extend InstanceName = strcat(ClusterId, '/', ContainerName)
| summarize by Namespace, InstanceName, ServiceName) on InstanceName
| where Namespace == 'namespace'
| project LogTime, ServiceName, CPU
| where ServiceName contains 'servicenaame'
```